# Can we get OS details from helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Is there any way I can get the OS details from helm.
say `Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS` is the OS image used, how can I get this from helm.

I know there is `Capabilities.KubeVersion` which has the details on `platform` but it gives

```
Platform:"linux/amd64"
```

which is not I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no.

The feature [Capabilities](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/7cad59091a9451b2aa4f95aa882ea27e6b195f98/pkg/chartutil/capabilities.go#L32) from Helm has only `Major`, `Minor`, `GitVersion`, `GoVersion`, `Compiler` and `Platform` info. `Platform` uses [`runtime.GOOS`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/) and [`runtime.GOARCH`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/) from Go that return only if OS is a Linux type, not its distribution.